Running yolov4 with OpenVino - GPU
I'm trying to compile OpenVINO on my Windows system with GPU enabled.
code:
from openvino.runtime import Core
core = Core()
model = core.read(model_path)
compiled_model = core.compile_model(model, device_name="GPU")

the code execution just stops at this line without throwing out any error.
What could be the reason for the same?
Openvino is able to detectg CPU and GPU, the code works fine when model is combined with CPU and just stops abruptly when compiled with GPU.
Thanks in advance

Please provide more context like more related code. It is hard to help with these 4 lines for your question.
